# Why the layout is changed when html newsletter sent to recipient?

Tags: html

My email html code, when i sent it via mailchimp the layers get destroyed and look completely different than normal. I've used table format but still it's not working. I've also used basic mailchimp teplate. But nothing is working. Here I attached the code:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta property="og:title" content="*|MC:SUBJECT|*" />
    <title>title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{margin:0;padding:0;font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;}.main{width:600px;margin:0 auto;display:block;overflow:hidden;}img{width:100%}.logo{background:url(img/logo.png) center center no-repeat;min-height:100px;border-bottom:3px #7A7A7A solid}.logo p{margin-top:60px}.title h1{color:#FF4013;font-size:68px;margin-top:15px;text-align: center;margin-bottom:15px}.subtitle p{color:#008CB4;border-top:1px #A8A8A8 solid;border-bottom:1px #A8A8A8 solid;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;font-size:18px;text-align:center;font-style:italic}.left{float:left;width:36%;background-color:#EBEBEB;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;text-align:justify}.left p{font-size:13px;line-height:16px}strong{line-height:25px}.left h4{color:#008CB4;border-bottom:1px dotted #008CB4;text-decoration:none}.right{float:right;width:57%;border-left:1px solid #B2B2B2;padding-left:10px}.right h2{color:#0C8CB4;font-size:20px}.right p{line-height:20px;font-size:15px}.right img{width: 100%!important;}.footer p{margin-top:30px;}.footer a{margin-top:30px;clear: both;} @media (max-width: 400px) {.title h1{font-size: 38px;}.right{float:none;clear: both;}.subtitle p{font-size: 14px;text-align: left;}.left{width: 55%;padding-left: 10px;} .left p{font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px;}}
    </style>
</head>

<body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0">

    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="backgroundTable">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <div class="main">
                                <div class="logo">
                                    <p style="float:left; color:#008CB4;">The Bharat Army Newsletter</p>
                                    <p style="float:right; color:#008CB4;">June 2015</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="title">
                                    <h1>BHARAT ARMY</h1>
                                </div>
                                <div class="subtitle">
                                    <p>Your Quarterly Newsletter for all things Indian Cricket!</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="left">
                                    <p>The Bharat Army will be travelingto India in March 2016 for the T20 World Cup. Limited number of seats will be available to join the tour and experience a World Cup</p>

                                </div>
                                <div class="right">
                                    <img src="img/1.png">

                                    <img src="img/2.png">
                                </div>
                                <div class="footer">
                                    <a style="color:#008CB4; float:left" href="ex.com">www.ex.com</a>
                                    <p style="color:#008CB4; float:right">1</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How an email displays depends on what is rendering it - all the various clients and platforms have often frustratingly inconsistent idiosyncrasies. Some email clients will, for instance, completely ignore everything within the `<head>` node, which in your case would make the email look very different.

You mention you are using MailChimp. Could I recommend their '[Inbox Inspector](http://mailchimp.com/features/inbox-inspector/)' service (which is powered by Litmus) where you can preview how your email will look in various clients.

If you don't pay for MailChimp, you won't be able to do this - but maybe try using a tool such as [Litmus](https://litmus.com/email-testing) directly instead (it's free for a bit).